# Why is there a “Hash Sum mismatch” when I switch to a bridged network connection with VMWare on macOS?

Tags: macos, kali-linux, vmware-fusion, apt, hashing

I'd prefer to run my virtual machine in a bridged configuration so that it appears as another machine on my network. However, when I switch from a NATed configuration to a Bridged connection I get "Hash Sum mismatch" when pulling from the Kali repos. I'm mostly curious why this occurs.

I switch to Bridged (Autodetect or Wi-Fi)

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt update              
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
462 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt install netcat                                                                                                   100 ⨯
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  netcat-openbsd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  netcat netcat-openbsd
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 462 not upgraded.
Need to get 50.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 130 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...
E: Failed to fetch http://kali.download/kali/pool/main/n/netcat/netcat_1.10-46_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:ceca713ddc75918359f7c6b41e1bee9359af9cceb248d5bfeb741b1c514b458a
    - SHA1:4951e4dac216f1958608fea30341174a90746506 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:e9b4e8f1f33d5c06c5bd7fbd3bdb3dfa [weak]
    - Filesize:9728 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:01edcc26407d805db589199b3ff20ea20fa4989a33f23f33de39ccdb7b8ee9d1
    - SHA1:5e437148e0d904a210c27e7352a5c3f7f901903f [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2e8df299034b35a2dc4d36fba0531cd7 [weak]
    - Filesize:9728 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Sat, 29 Aug 2020 23:12:44 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I switch to NAT

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt update                                                                                                           100 ⨯
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
462 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
                                                                                                                                    
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt install netcat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  netcat-openbsd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  netcat netcat-openbsd
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 462 not upgraded.
Need to get 50.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 130 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 netcat-openbsd amd64 1.217-3 [41.1 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 netcat all 1.10-46 [9,728 B]
Fetched 50.8 kB in 0s (116 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package netcat-openbsd.
(Reading database ... 277931 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../netcat-openbsd_1.217-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking netcat-openbsd (1.217-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package netcat.
Preparing to unpack .../netcat_1.10-46_all.deb ...
Unpacking netcat (1.10-46) ...
Setting up netcat-openbsd (1.217-3) ...
update-alternatives: using /bin/nc.openbsd to provide /bin/nc (nc) in auto mode
Setting up netcat (1.10-46) ...
Processing triggers for kali-menu (2021.1.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.3-2) ...
```

- Player Version 12.1.1 (17801503)
- Kali Linux VMWare 2021.1 64-Bit (https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/)
- macOS BigSur (11.2, 11.3)

I've tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505775/debian-apt-packages-hash-sum-mismatch
But I end up getting "signatures were invalid"...

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt-get update 
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Err:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.or
g>
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid
: BADSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: if you wait a day and try to reproduce these results for the hash sums, do they remain the same? That check is designed to ensure that the data was downloaded completely and correctly. as for the kali signing issue, have you ingested the public key for that repository?

Comment: > if you wait a day and try to reproduce these results for the hash sums, do they remain the same? Yes, this issue seems to persist across days. > as for the kali signing issue, have you ingested the public key for that repository? No, but are the signing keys removed by the steps of that answer I posted? I'm pretty sure apt-get clean just cleans caches, not keys. Same with "/var/lib/apt/lists/", I don't see keys in that directory.

Comment: This question is asked here. Not sure if it is the same OP :-) https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Kali-Linux-apt-update-returns-Hash-Sum-mismatch-error-Fusion-12/td-p/2816761

No solution yet.

I just had the same issue today. Was trying to bridge my Ubuntu VM to Wi-Fi on a macOS host. Weeks ago I had similar setup but was bridging with Ethernet instead of Wi-Fi. That worked.